# Native way to inform user there is a mobile app?

Tags: mobile-application

Often when viewing a website on a mobile device you'll get a notification that a mobile app is available, or if you already have the app downloaded you'll have the option to open the URL in the app.

Is there a native way to do this or are these notifications always custom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When users click on a link or download a file and the suggestion pops up to open the respective app, that's called deep linking. iOS labels it as [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) and Android uses [App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links).